# Why is the Range.Find working for only certain column names? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The goal is to search for a specific column header..in this case "Paid to Date" (exact match only) and insert a new column right before it and name it. 
This formula does not pick up the column even though it is there..but if i change the find(what:="Paid to Date") to another column such as "Close Date"..it works..but then i tried other columns and some work and some don't ..trying to figure out what is the reason for this?

```
 Sheets(NewSheet).Select
    Set ColHeaders = Range("A4:CD4").Find(What:="Paid to Date", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If ColHeaders Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Paid to Date Column was not found."
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Columns(ColHeaders.Column).Insert
    Cells(4, ColHeaders.Column - 1).Value = "Paid On " & Month(Range("D2")) & "/" & Day(Range("D2"))
```

Comment: `LookAt:=xlWhole` is sensitive to extra spaces in the cell. Try with `LookAt:=xlPart` to see if that's the cause of failue.

Comment: Are any of your columns hidden?

Comment: @A.S.H that did not work :(

Comment: @TimWilliams no they are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `application.match` instead for a more reliable string location.

```
dim var as variant
with workSheets(NewSheet)
    var = application.match("Paid to Date", .rows(4), 0)
    if not iserror(var) then
         .columns(var).entirecolumn.insert
         .cells(4, var) = format(.cells(2, "D"), "\P\a\i\d \O\n mm/dd")
    end if
end with
```

In your original code you are not supplying enough parameters to the .Find operation to overcome settings that the user may have changed (and are being inherited into the VBA operation.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! However, I forgot to mention that I wanted to also copy and paste the values from another specific column (column AI) into this newly inserted column. How would I refer to this?

With my previous code this is how it was defined:    

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(5, ColHeaders.Column - 1), Cells(lr, ColHeaders.Column - 1)) = Range(Cells(5, "AI"), Cells(lr, "AI")).Value